# OBJLoader/ThreeJS :Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am getting Three.OBJLoader Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when i try to load a custom obj file.
I checked out [THREE.OBJLoader not working (TypeError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802699/three-objloader-not-working-typeerror) and i tried shuffling all insertions of OBJLoader.js but still nothing works.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="OBJLoader.js"></script>

    <script src="https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
    <!-- // <script src="https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script> -->

    <script>

    function init(){
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

                var object = event.content;

                object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                        child.material.map = texture;

                    }

                } );

                object.position.y = - 80;
                scene.add( object );

            });
        loader.load('gargoyle/gargoyle.obj');
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your script tags need to be in , objloader.js inclusion should be after the main three.js file, also double-check the path to OBJLoader.js

Comment: Very weird... I removed the event listener and just used loader.load('.../gargoyle.obj', function(object){ scene.add(object)} and it worked.... Thanks anyway:)

Comment: Did the same to fix it, but it seems like there should be another way~