# Toggle between multiple 3d models in three.js using dat.gui

Tags: javascript, three.js, dat.gui

I'm trying to toggle between multiple 3d models (loaded with OBJMTLLoader.js) rendered in my three.js scene. I'm using dat.gui to create a dropdown list of model names and when one is chosen, the scene will add the respective obj model to the scene and remove the original one.

Here, I'm loading 2 separate models and adding the second one to the scene and then setting up the dat.gui controls:

```
    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();

    loader.load("../assets/models/boardlego.obj", "../assets/models/boardlego.mtl", function (obj2) {
        obj2.name = 'lego2';
        });



    loader.load("../assets/models/boardlego2.obj", "../assets/models/boardlego.mtl", function (obj) {
        obj.name = 'lego';
        scene.add(obj);
    });

    camControl = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    // call the render function
    render();

    //set up dat.gui controls
    control = new function () {
        this.Templates = 'shortboard';
        }
    addControls(control);
    }
```

Then, the addControls function:

```
function addControls(controlObject) {
    var gui = new dat.GUI();
    gui.add(controlObject, 'Templates', ['shortboard', 'longboard', 'fish', 'funboard', 'simmons', 'parallel', 'gun']).listen();
```

Both models are loaded but only one is added to the scene. Is it possible to add the other model when the 'Templates' control is changed? I tried to create a separate function updateboard() and call it in the render function, like this:

```
function updateboard() {
    if(controlObject.Templates === "longboard"){
        scene.add(obj2);
    }
}
```

But it didn't work. I also tried to set up an if statement in the render function:

```
function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    if (scene.getObjectByName('lego')) {
        scene.getObjectByName('lego').scale.set(control.Length, control.Thickness, control.Width);  
    }

    if(control.Templates === "longboard"){
        scene.add(obj2);
        }
```

But it didn't work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Or if you can scout out an example that could help too! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Load your objects in array();

```
 var my_models();
 var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();

     loader.load("../assets/models/boardlego.obj", "../assets/models/boardlego.mtl", function (obj2) {
      obj.name = 'lego2';
     my_models.push(obj);
    });

    scene.add(my_models[0]); // 0 would be the first model 1 is the second
```

Comment: 'scene.add(my_models[0])' is only working if it is used in the loader function. when it is moved outside, like you have it, nothing is added to the scene... any idea why? @Careen

Comment: looks like you can only add one obj to the scene within the loader.load function. sort of mentioned in comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888479/render-obj-file-using-three-objloader)

Comment: Is there another loader for three.js that allows you to add multiple .obj's (or any other 3d files) to the scene and toggle them on or off? @mrdoob